# Select specific og image from multiple for whatsapp

Tags: html, laravel, whatsapp

I have these:

```
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image"  content="{{ cdn('/img/web/concert.jpg') }}"/>
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image"  content="{{ cdn('/img/web/logo.png') }}"/>
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image"  content="{{ cdn('/favicon-32x32.png')}}"/>
```

So when I share on facebook for example, it correct picks the biggest (concert)

Whatsapp picks logo, which is the medium one and then crops it, leaving the logo crop.

So the question is: How do I make whatsapp to embed the favicon in rich texts?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: it was an error Mr..